# How to play streamed mp3 file from my golang webassembly client?

Tags: go, mp3, webassembly

I am coding a webassembly client for my music server [mifasol](https://github.com/jypelle/mifasol).

I'm querying the server via a REST API to download mp3/flac files to play. On the client side I get an [io.ReadCloser corresponding](https://github.com/jypelle/mifasol/blob/b696cb6fc06b915f337aed0457bbf1769c89f3d3/restClientV1/song.go#L44) to the file in question. I would like to play this file in the browser in streaming mode. Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: For now I'm getting by with a <audio> tag, and I'm using Go to populate the src attribute.
But to do so, I had to modify my backend so that my API accepts the token both in the url parameters and in the header Bearer field (sadly, you can't customize the header of requests with a <audio> tag).
But it's ugly, and it complicates the renewal of expired tokens

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.